# How to make auto login after registration in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have encounterd a problem while regiserting user in laravel, `$user` suppose to be array which contains all array element while auto login the following code results **false**. The password save in the database is `hash::make('password')`.

```
$user_id = $this->user_model->addUser($user);
$post = array('password' => $pass_for_auth, 'email' => $email);
var_dump(Auth::attempt($post,true));die;
```

Can any one tell me what is the correct problem

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try to login the user through his `$user_id`. So your code will be:

```
$user_id = $this->user_model->addUser($user);
$post = array('password' => $pass_for_auth, 'email' => $email);
Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);
```

You created the user so it returns an user_id, with the user_id you can login the user.

Hope this works!

More information at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Comment: This works well, but on the production, I sometimes get a "Page expired" error. Any idea?

Comment: @ishanshah that is something with the csrf token

Answer (score 13):

This would be the standard way to do user registration - you create a new user model instance and pass it to Auth::login() :

```
// do not forget validation!
$this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);

$data = $request->all();

$user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

Auth::login($user);
```

Comment: what is this Auth Class? Can you specify the full namespace?

Comment: @RameshPareek No need for it. It has an alias. Just `use Auth;` it. If you really want, you can find the path in `config/app.php`'s `aliases` key, which is: `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth`.