# How to create an entry in another table during registration?

Tags: php, laravel

How to create an entry in the second table during user registration?

table.users -> table_2.users_info > table_2.users_info.table.users.id

```
$model =   User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
 
        $user = new UserInfo();
        $user->user_id = $model->id;
        $user->save();
```

This code does not automatically log in after registration

Comment: what is that code from, where does it live? if you are talking about the `create` method on the `RegisterController` you should notice that it returns the user from the method.  There is also a `registered` method you can override which gets called after the user is created

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make auto login after registration in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884306/how-to-make-auto-login-after-registration-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

In your `RegisterController` you can override the registered method like:

```
   /**
     * The user has been registered.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        // Anything you want to do here.
        $info = new UserInfo();
        $info->user_id = $user->id;
        $info->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will work fine, but in order to automatically log in after that you have to make something like:

```
Auth::login($model);
```

after your code.

Also, please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884306/how-to-make-auto-login-after-registration-in-laravel)

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in   

RegisterController.php ;(